# Construct the Riemann surface of the function $f(z)=((z-1)(z-2)(z-3))^{2/3}$.

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces

Construct the Riemann surface of the function $f(z)=((z-1)(z-2)(z-3))^{2/3}$.

1,2 and 3 are branch points. But how can we determine $\infty$ is also a branch point. And how can we determine branch cuts? Thanks.

Comment: Do you know how to handle simpler examples, such as $f(z) = \sqrt{1 - z^{2}}$? If not, that would be a good place to start. :)

Comment: Your surface will be a $3$-fold covering of the complex plane (because of the cube root); you'll need to make some branch cuts among the point $1$, $2$, $3$, and $\infty$, and glue the copies across slits. Once you've done this in simpler examples (square roots and cube roots with only two branch points, and square roots with four branch points, say), it should be straightforward to carry out the details here.